# How to have a standard block kit interactive component look like a modal input

Tags: slack-api, slack-block-kit

I'm building a modal that has several select inputs on it. The values entered get posted to my server when the user clicks the modal submit button. However, for one of the selects I need it to post to the server immediately when the user interacts with it - and from what I understand, inputs don't do this.

So, I'm using an "Actions" layout block for one of the static select elements. However, the select looks nothing like the equivilent input static select. It's smaller and doesn't fill the full width of the video. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input staticSelect and set the dispatchAction to true

```
       {
            "dispatch_action": true,
            "type": "input",
            "element": {
                "type": "plain_text_input",
                "action_id": "plain_text_input-action"
            },
            "label": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Label",
                "emoji": true
            }
        }
```

this works for the staticSelect as well